# cannot locate symbol __isnanf referenced by libsupportjni.so

Tags: android, android-support-library

When i run my application on devices with api 17 i see this exception:

```
Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol __isnanf referenced by libsupportjni.so

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: at android.app.Application.<init>(Application.java:15)
```

while this exception doesn't occur in higher api versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it.
this issue was an "advanced profiling" related problem.
i disabled it and it works!
Go to

> Run -> Edit Configurations -> Profiling

, and uncheck "**Enable advanced profiling**"